# how should I convert VAriant from C++ in C#

Tags: c#, visual-c++, var

Hy! I have the following code in Visual C++ 6 and I want to convert it in C#.

```
SAFEARRAY * psa =   NULL;
SAFEARRAYBOUND rgsabound;
rgsabound.lLbound = 0;  
rgsabound.cElements = infoList.GetCount();
psa = SafeArrayCreate(VT_BSTR, 1, &rgsabound);
    ......

VARIANT listaF;
V_VT(&listaF) = VT_ARRAY|VT_BSTR;
listaF.parray   =   psa;
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: I`ve tried to make a     List<string> listaF = new List<string>()  but it is not the same and I don`t know what is that safearray in C#

Comment: does this [SAFEARRAY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.ole.interop.safearray.aspx) work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

safearray is an array in COM/OLE (see the [reference from Sanjeevakumar Hiremath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.ole.interop.safearray.aspx)), [BSTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221069.aspx) is a COM/OLE string. A [variant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221627.aspx) is a generic structure that can store many types of data.

What you have then is a safearray of BSTR wrapped in a VARIANT. In C# you can represent something like this with a simple array of strings.

```
string[] listaF = new string[infoList.GetCount()];
```

good luck.